# Send request to URL every second using python flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to send the request to a particular URL to get its status code every second. I am using the flask to do this.

What is the best way to do this?

```
@app.route('/')
def status_code_check():

    r = requests.head("https://www.google.co.in/")
    return "Status Code Is: %d" % r.status_code
```

Output is:

> Status Code Is: 200

Also, I have a set of URLs, I want it to send the request to all URLs in parallel/simultaneously and post the status update.

I don't have any development background. Hence, sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: Every second? Are you sure those sites are happy for you to do that?

Comment: These will be the internal URLs of our own services. So, We actually need data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using flask at all?
If you want to make a request every few seconds, a simple python program would be easier.
If you need to report the status (as in your example) via HTTP, flask is a great choice.

In your current model, you have basically two choices:
1. Calling your flask URL from a client every second. (e.g. using javascript in a browser). But if the client is down, the URL is not polled.
2. Run your polling function on a thread. The result is store somewhere and the flask url simply reports this last status.

Comment: Yes, I want to check the status code of each URL at every time instance. Hence, Opted for the flask. I will opt for the first option.
How can I pass multiple URLs at once in this function? Do you recommend it from a file or Inside this script? So that flask app can give the status of all URLs in the page.

Comment: Also, Is there any way in which this Flask app can recall every URL every second to give the current status of the URL without using any Javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I see your words, but their meaning eludes me. Please try to specify your problem in real english.